# Error 9: Subscript out of range when using open private

Tags: vba

The code works fine without using the `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`

and returns an error when used on the following line(s)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws_str As String

ws_str = "EOSL"
```

'Code Stops Here -->

```
Set ws = Worksheets(ws_str)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
```

Please help

Comment: Have you checked if a sheet "EOSL" exists? If it is part of the workbook with the code, I would also suggest to use "ThisWorkbook.sheets(ws_str)

Comment: Sounds like that sheet doesn't exist in the workbook that you are trying to open. But 
we can do no more than guess. If you want something more than guesses, please give more details, enough for the question to be a [mcve].

Comment: Also, the fact that you are using `On Error Resume Next` isn't a good sign. There are valid uses of it, but most uses that I have seen have been as a bandaid to make buggy code run.